# How do I properly store a javascript template, so that it isn't instantiated multiple times

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and therefore [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) to render my templates. My templates get rendered in `<script>` tags and then I use jQuery to grab their html.  My backbone view looks like this:

```
App.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className:'well',

    events: {
        'click .continue': 'handleContinueClick',
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($("#ItemTemplate").html())
        this.render()
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({model:this.model}))
    },

    handleContinueClick: function(e) {
        alert('Clicked!')
    }
})
```

My Issue is I would like to only go and grab the html once and only once for this particular type of view so that if I have a lot of items it doesn't go searching the html for this template each time.

Basically how do I properly store the template variable at the `ItemView` object level (not instance of the view) keeping in mind that the retrieval of the html has to wait until after  page load (so that I can guarantee the template html is available).

Comment: Is there a reason you're worrying about this?  I do hope you understand the evils of premature optimization.

Comment: sure, if someone can tell me it doesn't matter, I'm cool with that. you're right it's prolly early, I'm just curious.

Comment: @JayC - you're basically saying "DOM access for the same thing, multiple times, is premature optimization" which is pretty far from the truth. If the data never changes, only request it once.

Comment: @JayC - What does it matter why he's worrying about it? He may not even be working on a project at all, but is instead just simply trying to learn about best practices because he is interested. In either case if he wanted to know "when" to optimize I'm sure that's how the question would have been phrased.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can build a very simple object that caches the templates for you:

```
TemplateCache = {
  get: function(selector){
    if (!this.templates){ this.templates = {}; }

    var template = this.templates[selector];
    if (!template){
      var tmpl = $(selector).html();
      template = _.template(tmpl);
      this.templates[selector] = template;
    }

    return template;
  }
}
```

Then in your view, you can call `TemplateCache.get` and pass in your template selector.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  template: "#ItemTemplate",

  render: function(){
    var template = TemplateCache.get(this.template);
    var html = template(this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(html);
  }
});
```

The first time you call `TemplateCache.get` for a given selector, it will load it from the DOM. Any subsequent calls to get the template will load it from the cached version and prevent the extra DOM access call.

FWIW: I have a much more robust version of the `TemplateCache` object in my Backbone.Marionette framework: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette

Comment: Is there a measurable advantage to doing things this way? No really, I'm curious.  And why wouldn't you go ahead and use _.template in your TemplateCache?

Comment: Just to clarify:  why wouldn't you cache the template constructor instead of or as well as the html string itself?

Comment: @JayC - there is a measurable difference in performance at some point, yes. see the book "High Performance JavaScript" for more info. As for calling _.template in the TemplateCache, yes that would be a good thing to do. I just didn't think about that when I wrote the answer here. :)

Comment: @JayC just for fun, I put together a JSPerf test: http://jsperf.com/dom-select-vs-cache ... I don't know if this test is perfect, but it should illustrate the difference. Whether or not the difference is noticeable in most real use cases... maybe not.

Comment: I updated the answer to pre-compile the template in teh TemplateCache, like @JayC suggested.

Comment: Derrick, the JSPerf test?  That's awesome!  I've seen that website before, but I've never made my own tests for it, and this demonstrates exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you!

Comment: HOwever, I did add my own tests for it http://jsperf.com/dom-select-vs-cache/2 , and they do kinda line up with what I was thinking: searching the DOM isn't going to be that much more expensive than searching a dictionary (or rather, I guess in this case searching "this"), though you do save some time doing all that. (again, it's a small page, so I might not be fairly judging the test.  The real time saver appears to be precompiling the template, though, and I'm certainly going to keep that in mind!

Comment: And, erm (this is awkward)... I think in your `render`, the line `var html = _.template(this.model.toJSON());` now needs to be `var html = template(this.model.toJSON());`, cause you've already done that. Too many template properties and variables to keep track of. :-D

Comment: oops. :) thanks for the tip on that. fixed the call to `template(...)` - also, nice addition to the jsperf test! precompiled is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @JayC - The difference is that the size and depth of the DOM, as well as the complexity of the selectors makes the lookup time quite volatile, where pulling from a pre-indexed cache will return consistently in the same amount of time.

Comment: @Derick posted in his blog a nice article with all the info of this  http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/10/javascript-performance-pre-compiling-and-caching-html-templates/

Answer (score 5):

Most Backbone examples I've seen do it like this. This will only traverse the DOM once to parse the template when the page finishes loading and use that for each `new ItemView()`.

```
App.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#ItemTemplate").html()),

    className:'well',

    events: {
        'click .continue': 'handleContinueClick',
    },

    ...
});
```

http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html#section-21

Comment: There's a danger in doing that, in that your template may not load at all. http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/

Comment: If this code appears after the template (and therefore after the template is loaded), then there shouldn't be any danger. Simple and readable.  This is my preferred technique.

Answer (score 1):

You could muck around with `prototype.template` by hand and compile the template the first time you create an instance of your view. Something like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    if(!this.constructor.prototype.template)
        this.constructor.prototype.template = _.template($("#ItemTemplate").html());
    this.render();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/e6y3F/

The trick is to get your hands on the right `prototype`.

Comment: This method will render the template as well as parse it. If you're template takes input data to render, then you should leave template.render() for the View's template function.

Comment: @supershnee: Not sure what you mean, `_.template(html)` just returns the compile template function, I see no call to `this.template()` anywhere and `template.render()` would probably just produce a TypeError as compiled Underscore templates don't have `render` methods. Your answer below is pretty much the same thing as mine.

Comment: Sorry, meant this.render().

Comment: @supershnee: I still don't see your point. `render` is, presumably, filling in the template, `initialize` is just stashing the compiled template function in the view's prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the compiled template in a closure so that only the instances of ItemView can access it:

```
(function() {

    var template;

    App.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

        className:'well',

        events: {
            'click .continue': 'handleContinueClick'
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            template = template || _.template($("#ItemTemplate").html());
            $(this.el).html(template({model:this.model}));
        },

        handleContinueClick: function(e) {
            alert('Clicked!');
        }

    });

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using prototype:

```
 initialize: function(option) {
     if (!this.template) App.ItemView.prototype.template = this.template || _.template($('ItemTemplate').html());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use raw HTML-code or you might get HTML-code from DOM-element which should had rendered before this script

**1) raw HTML-code:**

```
var app = app || {};

app.TreeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    id: 'js-tree',
    template: _.template('<li data-id="<%- id %>"><%- Name %></li>'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.model.each(this.renderRow, this);
        return this;
    },
    renderRow: function(model) {
        var html = template(model);
        this.$el.append(html);
        return this;
    }
});
```

**2) or HTML-code from rendered DOM-element:**

```
var app = app || {};

app.TreeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    id: 'js-tree',
    template: _.template($("#js-template-tree-item").html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.model.each(this.renderRow, this);
        return this;
    },
    renderRow: function(model) {
        var html = template(model);
        this.$el.append(html);
        return this;
    }
});
```